# How to specify the end of the line with the dotall modifier in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find the CREATE SQL queries from a file, to simplify the task I wrote `#end` at the end of each query, but the search continues and I'm getting a few results in one array index (or simply a continuation of the file), instead of one.

```
preg_match_all('/CREATE.*#end/su', $sql, $queries);
```

SQL example:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblname` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `label` (`label`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8#end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that `*` is *greedy* by default. That means it finds the *longest* match it can, not the shortest. Make it ungreedy: `.*?`, now it will stop matching as soon as it finds a single match.